# Youtube URL auto correction/replacement automation google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

I want to find out if there is any chance to automate a website link by writing macros in google chrome.

My point is : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObwXTI8We1E&spfreload=10` (youtube is restricted)  should be auto corected/replaced from 'watch' to '%2ftv'. So
`https://www.youtube.com/%2Ftv?spfreload=10#/watch/video/idle?v=ObwXTI8We1E&resume` (youtube tv is accessible) gets generated and be loaded.

I cannot use extensions (imacros or any) in chrome, as it is disabled by my system admin.

I know I can manually do it but, just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use bookmarklets instead. So add page to 'Bookmark Manager', enter some name and the following url:

```
javascript:{window.location.href=window.location.href.replace(/(.+)(v=%5Cw+)&(.+)/,%22$1%22+%22$3%22+%22#/watch/video/idle?%22+%22$2%22+%22&resume%22).replace(%22watch%22,%22%2Ftv%22);}
```